# Accept user variable and create a template.py using python[2,7][redhat 6.7]

Tags: python, shell, unix, scripting

Scenario : I have a test.py file which has the following code.

```
import json
import os
import sys
def check()
    url = os.popen("curl api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797 2>dev/null")
    uri = json.loads(url)
    f_check = file("/home/1/file1.txt",'r')
    f_data = f_check.read()
    chk_data = int(f_data)
    f1 = open("file1.txt", "w")
    n1 = f1.write(str(uri) + "\n")
    f1.close()
```

In the above mentioned test.py file is in location " /home/check " I want to use this as a template file which can be used to deploy for other uses in different location say "/home/word" just Changing some variables in it like url and file1.txt file location which user will provide.
I couldn't find a convenient way to do that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Call `test.py` with Parameters. E.g. `python test.py <url> <filename>. Second make `test.py` a `module` and `import`  into a script at higher level.

Comment: thanks , do I need to provide the full path of file name as parameters?

Comment: In general YES, depends from which folder you call the script. Your example code saves into the current folder.

Comment: I have done the test.py as template and test1.py as main script and imported the test.py script into test1.py but its not working with that way too.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: ...  Changing some variables in it like url and file1.txt file location

It's unclear what you want to do with `chk_data`.
Tried your example code and found you are reading `chk_data` but doing nothing with it afterwards. Please edit your Question and explain this more detailed with example data.

---

This example can be used with different `url`, `file lcation`and `filename`.

> **Note**: I use `module urllib` instead of `os.popen("curl...`.

**First Solution**, passing Parameters from Terminal Window:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

def check(url, params, filename):
    params = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
    url = "{}?{}".format(url, params)

    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
        json_response = json.loads(f.read().decode('utf-8'))

    with open(filename, 'w') as f_out:
        f_out.write(str(json_response))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = sys.argv[1]
    params = {}
    for param in sys.argv[2].split(' '):
        key, value = param.split('=')
        params[key] = value

    if url == 'openweathermap.org':
        url = 'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
        params['appid'] = 'b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1'

    check(url, params, sys.argv[3])
```

> **Usage**:
>
> ```
> :#  python openweathermap.org "id=2172797" /home/word/my_file.txt
> ```

---

**Second Solution**, using `test.py` as a Python `module` with `import check`.
Parameters inside a new Python Script.

> **Note**: This requires `home.check.test` is in your `PYTHONPATH`!

Create a new `*.py` file, e.g `openweathermap.py`

```
from home.check.test import check

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
    params = {'id':'2172797', 'appid':'b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1'}
    check(url, params, '/home/word/my_file.txt')
```

> **Usage**:
>
> ```
> :#  python /home/check/openweathermap.py
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***